# click on a link tag while using jquery ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link tag that doesn't contain a url, but instead it has javascript. I'm using jQuery and when I try the ".click()" function, it doesn't work. I searched through the website and found some answers but all of them open the "href" of the link tag and these answers won't be helpful in my case, here's an example of the code :

```
<button onclick="ClickMe();">CLick Me!</button>
<a id="test" href="javascript:alert('hi');">Alert</a>
<script>
    function ClickMe() {
        $("#test").click();
    }
</script>
```

This is a shared project and my ability to change the html of the page is very limited.

Here's the example : http://jsfiddle.net/Ayman_Mohamed/ygDmW/1/

Comment: <a id="test" onclick=(alert("hi")) >Alert</a>

Answer (score 2):

Use a Vanilla Javascript!

```
function ClickMe() {
   $('#test')[0].click();
}
```

[Here is your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygDmW/3/)

Comment: @Mohsen try this http://jsfiddle.net/g5tCk/ `:)` I have changed few thigns though id to class but then indexing will have to be mentioned hence not generic solutions `:)`

Comment: @Mohsen: You can 1) have different id name 2) change id to class 3) use eq.

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/sp3WR/

If you want to use `href` use it like this

Also all the answers above contains the `click` way as well.

Hope this helps the cause `:)`

**code**

```
function ClickMe() {
      window.location.href = $("#test").prop('href');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fire click of anchor tag having id test which you havent binded you put alert on `href` not binding `click`, bind click event with href you will be able to fire it using `click()`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ygDmW/6/)**

*Html*

```
<button onclick="ClickMe();">CLick Me!</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a id="test" href="javascript:alert('Hi');" onclick="alert('href clicked')">Alert</a>
```

*Javascript*

```
function ClickMe() {
    $("#test").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("hi!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click Me" />

</body>
</html>
```